# Google login redirect error with Azure Mobile Service Javascript client SDK

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

When my web client tried to login google with Azure Mobile Javascript sdk, it gave me an error.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js"></script>

  <script> 
  function signIn(){    
     var MobileServiceClient = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;
     var client = new MobileServiceClient('https://thehome.azurewebsites.net', 'xxxx');

    client.login("google").done(function (results) {
         alert("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);
    }, function (err) {
        alert("Error: " + err);
    });
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="signIn()">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I used sample code from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-html-how-to-use-client-library/ .
If I click the button, I got below error.

```
Cannot GET /login/google?completion_type=postMessage&completion_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fthehome.azurewebsites.net
```

My iOS application works well with server app, but only web client has this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error it gives you?  If you show the [JavaScript Console](http://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/), are there any error messages within the console?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that login with a provider like Google does a ping from their servers to your server after the login.

Right now, it's complaining that your service in azure *thehome* is not there.

Please follow this guide to configure your Google account to make it work with Mobile Services:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-google-authentication/